# htaccess rules: no doubles, no index, no extensions, correct redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create .htaccess rules to fix all of that, here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ru\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/ru\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^en\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/en\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^it\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/it\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^fr\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/fr\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^de\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/de\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^uk\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/uk\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^es\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/es\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,R=404,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /en/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error_page.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_page.html
```

Using those rules I still have problems:
When I try to access the page with .php I got an error:
http://www.example.com/en/corniglia.php
But I prefer to get a redirect to the page without extension. When I fix this - something else brakes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your code this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /en/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error_page.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_page.html

RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?incinqueterre\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(ru|en|it|fr|de|uk|es)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: At the moment found only one error, that is not very important: http://www.incinqueterre.com/en/manarola.phpSLASH it redirect to the index

Comment: see update but isn't `http://www.incinqueterre.com/en/manarola.php/` an invalid URL?

Comment: yes, it's invalid, but it doesn't return 404 error. Now it looks very good, thank you:)